# search plugin doesn't work on php files but only html

Tags: php, search

I'm here, because I need some help about a searching form display in php.
I've this PHP file (Is a templateMonster plugin rd-search.php) that searches  some words into website that users search and types. There is a problem that I can't figure out, because words are searched in html files but not in php files. Can you tell me if it's possible make php files allowable filetypes to search in? I've tried also to add this code

`$search_in = array('php','html', 'htm');`

but it doesn't work. Why?

To view full code click here:[enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/kJyrzM5i)

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['s'])) {
    die('You must define a search term!');
}

$highlight = true; //highlight results or not
$search_in = array('html', 'htm'); //allowable filetypes to search in
$search_dir = '..'; //starting directory
$recursive = true; //should it search recursively or not
define('SIDE_CHARS', 15);
$file_count = 0;
$search_term = mb_strtolower($_GET['s'], 'UTF-8');

if ($search_term == "?s=") {
    $search_term = "";
}
?>
```

Here below there is a link that explains what I would like to do:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the whole code snippet along with precise description.

Comment: You define `$search_in` but don't use it?

Comment: I've the full code in php but I don't know how to post here, because it tells me that the code is too long to post.

Comment: you can use https://pastebin.com/ to provide full code

Comment: @monstercode Thank you very much for your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe I've found the solution. The problem was in the html code, I solved the issue simply adding aa specific class to a search form.

Thank to all. My best regards to all